# How to fix? 'E1101:Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'h' member' and 'E1101:Instance of 'QuantumCircuit' has no 'cx' member'

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm using this simple code to test my Qiskit and learn how to use it but it keeps giving this problems, how do I fix it (Using VS Code and Anaconda Python 3.7)

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
from qiskit import execute
# Create a Quantum Register with 3 qubits.Basicaly creating the number of qubits your system will use
q = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
# Create a Quantum Circuit acting on the q register. Declaring the Circuit, this circuit shall create a GHZ state
circ = QuantumCircuit(q,)
# Add a H gate on qubit 0, putting this qubit in superposition.
circ.h(q[0])
# Add a CX (CNOT) gate on control qubit 0 and target qubit 1, putting
# the qubits in a Bell state.
circ.cx(q[0], q[1])
# Add a CX (CNOT) gate on control qubit 0 and target qubit 2, putting
# the qubits in a GHZ state.
circ.cx(q[0], q[2])
#Draws the circuit
from qiskit.tools.visualization import circuit_drawer
circuit_drawer(circ)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no errors in your program.

Pylint is a static code analysis tool and sometimes it gets confused and emits false positives. In this case, gate methods (`h`, `cx` and others) are added to `QuantumCircuit` dynamically at a later point, so Pylint cannot detect them. See [`qiskit.extensions.standard`](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/tree/master/qiskit/extensions/standard) if you'd like to learn how this works.

The simplest “fix” for this “error” is making Pylint ignore those classes in your [`pylintrc`](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options) (if your installation of Pylint comes pre-built into your IDE, you'll have to see if the IDE has some particular way of configuring Pylint).

```
[TYPECHECK]

# List of class names for which member attributes should not be checked (useful
# for classes with dynamically set attributes). This supports the use of
# qualified names.
ignored-classes=QuantumCircuit,CompositeGate
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are following the code from the notebook `getting_started_with_qiskit_terra`.
However it should be

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(q)
```

instead of

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(q,)
```

according to this notebook.
Can you try removing the coma and running?

Comment: Trailing commas are generally allowed in Python, including in function/class calls.

Comment: Did not know that. It is ugly though.